# Play Video on CPU: "VIA Samuel 2", 797 MHZ

Tags: windows, windows-xp, video, vlc-media-player

Please help me track down if the hardware is able to output video.

- VLC 1.0 - 2.x.current are not possible to install (Problem occured, send report)
- VLC 0.3.x (very old) installs but hangs after 2sec playing.
- Other Players like Window MediaPlayer Classic are also not working (no pic, but sound, codec installed).

Could it be that the following CPU or MotherBoard is not capable to render/output Videos?

- CPU: VIA Samuel 2, 797 MHz
- Ram: 512 MB
- Motherboard: P3VB-VXL
- OS: Win XP SP2

I am very curious if there is a limitation at some hardware to output video.

Thanks for your wisdom on this.

Comment: the via samuel 2 is incapable of playing avi`s etc,it will play mpegs,but not much else,so dont go trying a new graphics card or anything of that sort you will just be throwing your money away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's just so many possibilities here i'm not sure where to start.

Now, usually this wouldn't be an issue, but on such a low end system, i need to ask - is it a standard install of windows, or a stripped down one? I note many people stick to older versions of windows for resource reasons so its a possibility. If it is a modified version, things can get trickier.

What's your processor and ram usage looking like? I've experimented on VERY low ram usage with VLC and while i used less (128 mb) and a different OS (linux), i got no issues. That was a VM however, and the Via c3 is comparable to a pentium III

Do portable versions of VLC work? This might tie back to the first point, or that the issue is with the installer, not the video player.

Finally, could you try running a stripped down linux install and seeing if it works there? [slitaz](http://www.slitaz.org/en/) may be a good option

Comment: hi, thx for your concerns. it's a standard install. i tried tinycore (< slitaz) and puppy from live-cd which don't play the video (avi) too on vlc and standard player. using VM i get it working also with 128mb ram. i guess the problem is related to the mobo and to a minor degree to the weak cpu. i just never heard from anyone that there are limitations to video rendering on older hardware. under the c3 samuel 2 the portable vlc doesn't work either. its strange that it outputs 2 sec of video under vlc 0.3.x and than breaks. maybe the mobo-intern graphic can't handle the load. cpu is 100% usage.

Comment: "cpu is 100% usage" I suspect thats the thing - you are rendering everything via your CPU and that simply dosen't have the grunt to handle it. The inability to install anything newer is still odd tho.